# How get stream of selected image by user (BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(inputStream) returns null)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When loading the selected image of the user and passing the stream to `BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(inputStream)` I always get as result `null`.

I load the stream of the image like this:

`Stream stream = new Java.Net.URL(Uri.Parse($"file://{imageFile.Path}").ToString()).OpenStream();` I also tried many other variants like:

`BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(Activity.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri)` or `new Java.IO.FileInputStream(imageFile.Path)`

I have permissions for `WriteExternalStorage`. Whats causing the problem? How to fix it?

The sample project is available here https://github.com/mfe-/App10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use the content resolver. Unfortunately, the process is not consistent across sdk versions and even sometimes devices. Take a look at how the media picker plugin handles getting the file. I've actually ended up copy/pasting its GetFileForUriAsync method into my project.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin/Android/MediaPickerActivity.cs